# Passing of Value through URL and getting it through $_GET fails

Tags: php

I'm a PHP newbie, so please be considerate.

I'm trying to pass the doc_id (in the codes below) through the url to another page. Unfortunately, what shows up in the address bar when I click this link, is doc_id=

```
echo'<td><a href="view_profile.php?doc_id='.$row[doc_id].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you wish to view this record?\');">View Profile</a></td>';
```

This link actually works on other pages. I can't figure why it won't work on the one I'm using it on right now. Any ideas?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

that line is from this:

```
if($SearchBySpec) { $query="SELECT * FROM doctor where specialization='$SearchBySpec'"; $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error executing select query'.mysql_error());



echo'<table border="1" cellspacing="1">'; echo'<tr align="center">'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 width="80" class="auto-style2"><strong>Specialization</strong></td>'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 width="80" class="auto-style2"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 class="auto-style2" style="width: 103px"><strong>First Name</strong></td>'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 width="80" class="auto-style2"><strong>Middle Initial</strong></td>'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 width="90" class="auto-style2"><strong>School</strong></td>'; echo'<td bgcolor=#81F7D8 width="80" class="auto-style2"><strong>Hospital Assigned</strong></td>';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr align=center>"; echo "<td>$row[specialization]"; echo "<td>$row[last_name]"; echo "<td>$row[first_name]"; echo "<td>$row[middle_name]"; echo "<td>$row[school]"; echo "<td>$row[hospital_assigned]";

}

//echo"<td><a href='view_profile.php?doc_id=".$row[doc_id]."'>View Profile</a></td>";    echo'<td><a href="view_profile.php?doc_id='.$row[doc_id].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you wish to view this record?\');">View Profile</a></td>'; //echo'<td><a href="view_profile.php?doc_id='.$row[doc_id].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you wish to view this record?\');">View Profile</a></td>'; echo "<tr><td>There are ". mysql_num_rows($result). " record(s)found.</td></tr>"; echo "</table>"    ;

}
```

Comment: well, $row doesn't contain what you think it contains - var_dump($row) and see what you get, and also ensure you have all error reporting enabled.

Comment: It sounds like $row[doc_id] is empty. What do you get if you `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: Try to display $row[doc_id]. What does it show?

Comment: Hey guys, this is what I get:

bool(false)

Comment: @user1242749 I assume this data is coming from a mysql query and your query is returning 0 rows.

Comment: show how you construct the $row variable

Comment: okay, the codes are:


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<td>$row[specialization]";
echo "<td>$row[last_name]";
echo "<td>$row[first_name]";
echo "<td>$row[middle_name]";
echo "<td>$row[school]";
echo "<td>$row[hospital_assigned]";

}

Answer (score 0):

doc_id needs to be in quotes.

```
$row['doc_id'];
```

Also, where are you defining $row? If it's something like this:

```
$row=$_GET; // or
$row['doc_id']=$_GET['doc_id'];
```

Then you're fine.

Comment: PHP will assume that since there's no constant named `doc_id` that you meant `'doc_id'`. There'd be a warning too, something like: `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant doc_id - assumed 'doc_id'`, but it would still give you the same return value.

Comment: Unless there is a constant names doc_id. You're right, but either way, he still should take away the ambiguity and use quotes, good habit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly the `$row` variable doesn't have a `doc_id` (which you should be quoting, by the way: `$row['doc_id']`). It sounds like there's probably something going wrong before this line. Try executing `print_r($row)` to see what data you actually have.

Also, make sure that you have error reporting turned on. PHP tries to be a little too friendly to new users by ignoring errors for you -- nice at first, but ultimately just hides real issues from you.